# Odd behavior of list.remove with arbitrary class - comparing objects

Tags: python

I've noticed a somehow odd behavior of `list.remove` that couldn't be explained (by me at least) by going over the C source.

Consider this class:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, n1, n2):
        self.n1 = n1
        self.n2 = n2

    def __eq__(self, other):
        print('in eq')
        return vars(self) == vars(other)
```

And the following code:

```
a1 = A(1, 2)
a2 = A(1, 2)
li = [a1, a2]
li.remove(a1)
```

I would expect it to output `in eq` but it outputs nothing which means `A.__eq__` is not being called.

Neither this

```
a1 = A(1, 2)
a2 = A(2, 3)
li = [a1, a2]
li.remove(a1)
li.remove(a2)
```

triggers a call to `A.__eq__`.

Calling `remove` twice with the same object *does* end up calling `A.__eq__`, but (oddly enough) only once:

```
a1 = A(1, 2)
a2 = A(1, 2)
li = [a1, a2]
li.remove(a1)
li.remove(a1)
# 'in eq'
```

1. Why calling `remove` once doesn't call `A.__eq__`? How does `remove` know it found the object to be removed? It seems odd the Python implementation is using memory addresses for comparison even if we override `__eq__`.
2. Why does calling `remove` twice with the same object *is* calling `A.__eq__`, and why only once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The remove method uses `is` first before it use `==`, i.e. `__eq__`. So if it finds the object you would like to remove with `is`, the `__eq__` does not get called. It call `__eq__` only if it cannot find the object with `is`. So, when try to remove the object a second time it removes the object that is equal. In this case `a2`. Now `li` is empty:

```
>>> li.remove(a1)
>>> li.remove(a1)
>>> li
[]
```

When you call `li.remove(a1)` a third time you will et a `ValueError`

Comment: As I suspected. I wonder if there is a good historical reason for `remove` to use `is` first even if we override `__eq__`. I believe that the gained performance is neglectable.

Comment: If you have a large list to compare `is` can be much faster  than comparing each list element individually.