"in" operator for list does not call item's __eq__ method
This is the code setup:
from typing import Self, Iterable


class PersonNotFoundError(Exception):
    """Person not found in collection."""


class Person:
    """A person with a name."""

    def __init__(self: Self, name: str) -> None:
        self.name = name

    def __eq__(self: Self, other: Self) -> bool:
        print("Calling __eq__ in Person class")
        if type(self) != type(other):
            return NotImplemented
        return self.name == other.name


class PersonCollection:
    """A collection of persons."""

    def __init__(self: Self, iterable: Iterable[Person]) -> None:
        self._data: list[Person] = list(iterable)

    def __contains__(self: Self, person: Person) -> bool:
        if person in self._data:
            return True
        raise PersonNotFoundError


p = Person("Person1")
p2 = Person("Person2")
pc = PersonCollection([p, p2])
print(p in pc)  # Does not call Person.__eq__
print(p2 in pc)  # Does call Person.__eq__


Why isn't Person.__eq__ being called when evaluating p in pc? Since it wasn't called, and the result still comes back True, the person in self._data would have had to use reference equality instead. But why?

Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42275183/odd-behavior-of-list-remove-with-arbitrary-class-comparing-objects

This is answered in Making an object x such that x in [x] returns False, additionally Causes for inconsistent behavior when adding NaNs to a set may also be helpful reading.

Python won´t call __eq__ if an item already matches by id: (i.e. the object passed to __contains__ is the same instance as the one inside the container - as one could confirm with the is operator)
For a different instance of your Person class, with the same name, it will work as expected. I just pasted your snippet above in a REPL session, and them:

In [6]: from copy import copy

In [7]: p3 = copy(p)

In [8]: p in pc
Out[8]: True

In [9]: p3 in pc
Calling __eq__ in Person class
Out[9]: True


To be clear, "Python won´t call __eq__ if an item already matches by id" is a specific property of in for list/tuple. If you just tested p == p, it would perform equality testing, no identity testing.

Right, the behavior crucially relies on self._data being a list, and a particular performance optimization that they (CPython) decided to add for lists, but this answer makes it sound like all containers must behave like that.

All built-in containers for arbitrary objects (the others being dictionary, set and frozenset) will. Any other will do whatever its __contains__ methods say, of course. Moreover, I am obviously taking of the code in the O.P.

@wim It's not just a performance optimization. I'm not even convinced that was the main reason.

Well, it was added in 93d4481 by Raymond and is (still) commented as a "Quick result" in object.c. I think "guarantees that identity implies equality" is a consequence, and not a motivator (especially since this later caused trouble with nans).

@wim Ok, maybe speed was the main motivator back then. But when someone removed it, Raymond fought back solely with reasons about logic. Excerpt: "The "identity implies equality" rule isn't just an optimization, it is a deep assumption that pervades the language implementation. Lots of logic relies on it to maintain invariants." (And that's the only thing he said there about it being an optimization - That that's not all it is.)

The quircky object in all this story is actually NaN- and those are actually a bit hard to come by in "regular" (as opposed to numpy heavy) code - and people dealing with NaNs will usually have to learn their way, somehow (usually the hard way :-) )

(and on a second though, even for ´NaNs, the "containship" results comaparing with  isand falling back toeqmight make sense in most cases: the same NaN instance is reported as bring in the container, while other NaNs are not - for all other casesany(isnan(x) for x in c)` is the correct thing to do anyway.)

the reason Person.__eq__ is not called for p in pc is that p and the corresponding element in self._data are actually the same object (is equality), so Python never needs to fall back to calling the __eq__ method.
If you want to ensure that Person.__eq__ is always called, you need to modify your __contains__ method to iterate over the list and perform the comparison manually:
class PersonCollection:
    """A collection of persons."""
    def __init__(self: Self, iterable: Iterable[Person]) -> None:
        self._data: list[Person] = list(iterable)
    def __contains__(self: Self, person: Person) -> bool:
        for p in self._data:
            if p == person:  # This will call Person.__eq__
                return True
        raise PersonNotFoundError
 
p = Person("Person1")
p2 = Person("Person2")
pc = PersonCollection([p, p2])
print(p in pc)   # Now it will call Person.__eq__
print(p2 in pc)  # It will also call Person.__eq__

This way, you'll ensure that the Person.__eq__ method is called during the membership test.

But why does this only hold for the first element of the list?

@jensa: It compares one-by-one. Anything that doesn't pass the identity test falls back to the value-equality test. If the matching object isn't the first one in the list, it has to test that first element for identity, then equality, then move to the next where it passes the identity test.

@ShadowRanger Where can I find the documentation that explains this behavior of the __contains__ method (for lists for example)? This behavior was news to me.

@jensa: It's an implementation detail, not a guarantee. Most CPython built-ins perform equality testing via the PyObject_RichCompareBool API, which does document that identity testing overrides any custom equality operator (by contrast, PyObject_RichCompare, which returns an actual True or False, not 1 or 0, does not involve a shortcut for identity testing, yes, it's confusing). lists are a built-in, and PyObject_RichCompareBool is the most convenient API for implementing the comparison.

@jensa: In general, the answer to a lot of these questions is going to end up being "It's an implementation detail, consult the C source code". The identity test is cheap and can speed up certain code patterns, so they do it, and even if that wasn't a design goal of list.__contains__, the sheer convenience of PyObject_RichCompareBool means they'll use that behavior by default.

@ShadowRanger But the documentation says: "For container types such as list, tuple, set, frozenset, dict, or collections.deque, the expression x in y is equivalent to any(x is e or x == e for e in y)." And not in a "CPython implementation detail" paragraph.

@nocomment: I stand corrected, I was checking the wrong part of the docs. Guess they officially documented the consequences of that API choice. Now that you made me think about that, I recall some folks (PyPy reimplementation of some CPython built-ins at the Python layer?) having a bit of annoyance there, because the way they wrote things, the identity pretest wasn't easy/free, so maintaining precise feature compatibility with CPython was a light annoyance.
